# Why is code like i=i*2 considered O(logN) when in a loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, logarithm

Why because of the i=i*2 is the runtime of the loop below considered O(logN)?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N;) {
  code with O(1);
  i = i * 2;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean the line containing the multiplication? The overall loop has log complexity.

Comment: I mean, the overall loop, still new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at 1024 = 2<sup>10</sup>. How many times do you have to double the number 1 to get 1024?

```
Times    1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8     9      10
Result   2   4   8   16   32   64  128  256   512    1024
```

So you would have to run your doubling loop ten times to get 2<sup>10</sup> And in general, you have to run your doubling loop n times to get 2<sup>n</sup>. But what is n? It's the log<sub>2</sub> 2<sup>n</sup>, so in general if n is some power of 2, the loop has to run log<sub>2</sub>n times to reach it.

Answer (score 2):

To have the algorithm in `O(logN)`, for any N it would need (around) log N steps. In the example of N=32 (where log 32 = 5) this can be seen:

```
i = 1 (start)
i = 2
i = 4
i = 8
i = 16
i = 32 (5 iterations)
i = 64 (abort after 6 iterations)
```

In general, after `x` iterations, `i=2^x` holds. To reach `i>N` you need `x = log N + 1`.

PS: When talking about complexities, the `log` base (2, 10, e, ...) is not relevant. Furthermore, it is not relevant if you have `i <= N` or `i < N` as this only changes the number of iterations by one.

Answer (score 1):

**i** starts in **1**. In each iteration you multiply **i** by **2**, so in the **K-th** iteration, **i** will be **2<sup>K-1</sup>**.

After a number **K** of iterations, **2<sup>K-1</sup>** will be bigger than (or to) **N**.

this means **N ≤ 2<sup>K-1</sup>**

this means **log<sub>2</sub>(N) ≤ K-1**

**K-1** will be the number of iterations your loop will run, and since **K-1** is greater or equal to **log(N)**, your algorithm is logarithmic.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it pretty simply.

Claim:
For the `t`th (0 base) iteration, `i=2^t`
Proof, by induction.

Base: `2^0 = 1`, and indeed in the first iteration, `i=1`.

Step: For some `t+1`, the value of `i` is `2*i(t)` (where `i(t)` is the value of `i` in the `t` iteration). From Induction Hypothesis we know that `i(t)=2^t`, and thus `i(t+1) = 2*i(t) = 2*2^t = 2^(t+1)`, and the claim holds.

Now, let's examine our stop criteria. We iterate the loop while `i <= N`, and from the above claim, that means we iterate while `2^t <= N`. By Doing `log_2` on both sides, we get `log_2(2^t) <= log_2(N)`, and since `log_2(2^t) = t`,  we get that we iterate while `t <= log_2(N)` - so we iterate `Theta(log_2(N))` times. (And that concludes the proof).